# NetBeans 7.1 and Subversion 1.7

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans-7.1

We're moving our version control from some old VCS to SVN, for ease of integration with IDE's (we're using both NetBeans and IBM RAD).

In doing so, I set up a local repository with SlikSVN for win64 and started a server with the command `svnserve -d -r c:\repo\test`. I defined a basic group with an user-password pair (no anonymous access allowed). My authz is as follows:

```
[groups]
li_users=alessandro

[/]
@li_users=rw
```

I then created a test project on both RAD (fitted with Subclipse 1.8) and NetBeans and tried to import it into the newly created repository, with the following outcomes:

- On RAD, I didn't have any problem accessing/importing into repositories both via file:///c:/repo/test and svn://localhost/.
- On NetBeans, I could import the project "TestProject" using the file:///c:/repo/test, but I couldn't using the svn://localhost/ link. After I'm presented with the Import comment page and directory suggestion using the project name, it gives me this error: `org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: URL 'svn://localhost/TestProject' doesn't exist`

Funny thing is, when I browse my repository by any means, including clicking the "Browse" button on the import wizard, it shows the "TestProject" directory and I can't create another with the same name. Also, if I create (with the "Into a new Folder") and try to use another directory, it gives me the same error.

What's wrong there? I searched and it seems to be a bug with NetBeans, but I can't find a way around this bug.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, falling back to Subversion 1.6 is the only way to go, at least until NetBeans catches up with 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind coming across a few errors you can try out the development branch of Netbeans (7.2 Beta) It has SVN 1.7 bundled. I have both 7.1.2 and 7.2 Beta installed for this reason...